# Visual Studio, TFS and Git LFS: how do I setup remote storage?

Tags: git, visual-studio, tfs, windows-10, git-lfs

From [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/manage-large-files?view=tfs-2018):

> Git LFS is an extension to Git which commits data describing the large
>   files in a commit to your repo, and stores the binary file contents
>   into separate remote storage.

This sounds great, however I could not find anywhere how I can setup that remote storage? The whole point for us would be to not be using the same drive as our TFS server for binary files, which seems feasible with Git-LFS. I am pretty new to Git, we want to move from TFSVC to Git but keep TFS for the rest.

Comment: That's not the point of Git LFS. The point of Git LFS is to keep large binary files out of the Git repository; the actual storage location should not be relevant to you. What is your actual goal here?

Comment: Hey, well, the doc says "stores the binary file contents into separate remote storage". My goal is to save space - keep track of those binary files using version control, but store them in other locations than the TFS server itself.

Comment: @DanielMann " ...to keep large binary files out of the Git repository" that actually sounds pretty much like what I want to do...? But maybe I need some little education here, as I mentioned in the question I am pretty new to Git.

Comment: Then Git LFS is not a solution to the problem you're trying to solve. Git is great at tracking text changes to small files; it can't really track changes to binary files. So every time you change a binary file in a Git repo, it has to just store a completely new copy of the file. This means that the repository bloats up with old versions of complete binary files, drastically increasing the repo size and slowing it way down. Git LFS solves **that** problem.

Comment: *Your* stated goal is 1) keep the files out of version control. Git LFS does that. 2) Store the files somewhere other than your TFS database. Git LFS doesn't do that.

Comment: @DanielMann I am confused, what "and stores the binary file contents into separate remote storage." from microsoft documentation means, then?

Comment: Separate from the Git repo.

Comment: @DanielMann I am afraid I am irremediably lost. If it is separate from the Git repo, where is it then?? Isn't this exactly what I want, separate from the Git repo/TFS server??

Comment: The Git repo and the TFS server aren't interchangeable entities. The TFS datastore contains a ton of information that's not just your Git repos. It's just a database. The database has your Git repos in it. The database also has your LFS data in it. The problem that's being solved is that the LFS data isn't **in** the Git repo, which represents a major usability issue to the *consumers* of the Git repo. The data is all still present in the TFS database, LFS just solves the binaries-causing-repo-bloat problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214705/discussion-between-ctzstef-and-daniel-mann).

Answer (score 1):

You may check the documentation below:

https://help.github.com/en/enterprise/2.20/admin/installation/configuring-git-large-file-storage-to-use-a-third-party-server

By default, the Git Large File Storage client stores large assets on the same server that hosts the Git repository. But you can configuring Git Large File Storage to use a third party server. Try creating a Git LFS configuration file that points to the third party server:

```
# Show default configuration
$ git lfs env
> git-lfs/1.1.0 (GitHub; darwin amd64; go 1.5.1; git 94d356c)
> git version 2.7.4 (Apple Git-66)

> Endpoint=https://GITHUB-ENTERPRISE-HOST/path/to/repo/info/lfs (auth=basic)

# Create .lfsconfig that points to third party server.
$ git config -f .lfsconfig remote.origin.lfsurl https://THIRD-PARTY-LFS-SERVER/path/to/repo
$ git lfs env
> git-lfs/1.1.0 (GitHub; darwin amd64; go 1.5.1; git 94d356c)
> git version 2.7.4 (Apple Git-66)

> Endpoint=https://THIRD-PARTY-LFS-SERVER/path/to/repo/info/lfs (auth=none)

# Show the contents of .lfsconfig
$ cat .lfsconfig
[remote "origin"]
lfsurl = https://THIRD-PARTY-LFS-SERVER/path/to/repo
```

Comment: Merci, I will look into this, seems promising and this should surely work with a TFS server as well.

Comment: That involves standing up and maintaining a separate LFS server. There aren't really any enterprise-grade LFS-only hosting platforms, because the general expectation is that you'll just use the LFS implementation that's built in to your Git hosting platform. Implementing and maintaining a separate LFS server is a huge amount of effort compared to just increasing the amount of space available for your TFS database.

Comment: Do you think pointing to a third party server will help preserving the files timestamp there? That's something that was lost with TFVC and Git as compared with source safe - the best we can have is the check-in date, and this is not enough for certain types of files.

Comment: @CTZStef I didn't set up such a server before. Configuring Git Large File Storage to use a third party server may be a workaround of your requirement, but you would need to maintain another along with TFS. If possible, we suggest you not use a third party server.